# recursion in the memory in finding the height of a binary search tree

Tags: recursion

I am having a trouble understanding the recursion  that is happening in the 
     memory of the code below. How does the stack behave during this operation?

```c
typedef struct node
{
    struct node *left;
    int data;
    struct node *right;
}node;


int findheight(node *root)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        return 0;
    int left,right;
        left=findheight(root->left);
        right=findheight(root->right);
    if(left<right)
        return right+1;
    else
        return left+1;
}
```